# Java Gridbag layout fillPolygon not displaying?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, paintcomponent

How come the polygon I tell my program to display. Here is my code of the class I call.

```
package rubiksCube;
/*class that contains my paint component*/
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class Display extends JPanel{
    Polygon[][] p = {{new Polygon(),new Polygon(),new Polygon()},
                    {new Polygon(),new Polygon(),new Polygon()},
                    {new Polygon(),new Polygon(),new Polygon()}};
    int[] rx = {0,0,0,0};
    int[] ry = {0,0,0,0};
    int rsN = 0;
    public void renderSide(int sN,int[] x,int[] y){
        rsN = sN;
        ry = y;
        rx = x;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        g.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
        for(int y = 0;y<3;y++){
            for(int x = 0;x<3;x++){
                System.out.print(x);
                System.out.println(y);
                g.setColor(getColor(Main.j[rsN][(y*3)+x]));
                p[y][x].addPoint((((rx[0]-rx[3])*(y/3)+rx[0])-((rx[1]-rx[2]))*(y/3)+rx[1])*(x/3)+((rx[0]-rx[3])*(y/3)+rx[0]),((((ry[0]-ry[3])*(x/3)+ry[0])-((ry[1]-ry[2]))*(x/3)+ry[1]))*(y/3)+((ry[0]-ry[3])*(x/3)+ry[0]));
                p[y][x].addPoint((((rx[0]-rx[3])*(y/3)+rx[0])-((rx[1]-rx[2]))*(y/3)+rx[1])*(x+1/3)+((rx[0]-rx[3])*(y/3)+rx[0]),((((ry[0]-ry[3])*(x/3)+ry[0])-((ry[1]-ry[2]))*(x/3)+ry[1])*(y/3))+((ry[0]-ry[3])*(x/3)+ry[0]));
                p[y][x].addPoint((((rx[0]-rx[3])*(y/3)+rx[0])-((rx[1]-rx[2]))*(y/3)+rx[1])*(x+1/3)+((rx[0]-rx[3])*(y/3)+rx[0]),((((ry[0]-ry[3])*(x/3)+ry[0])-((ry[1]-ry[2]))*(x/3)+ry[1]))*(y+1/3)+((ry[0]-ry[3])*(x/3)+ry[0]));
                p[y][x].addPoint((((rx[0]-rx[3])*(y/3)+rx[0])-((rx[1]-rx[2]))*(y/3)+rx[1])*(x/3)+((rx[0]-rx[3])*(y/3)+rx[0]),((((ry[0]-ry[3])*(x/3)+ry[0])-((ry[1]-ry[2]))*(x/3)+ry[1]))*(y+1/3)+((ry[0]-ry[3])*(x/3)+ry[0]));
                g.fillPolygon(p[y][x]);
            }
        }
    }
    public Color getColor(int i){
        switch(i){
            case 0:
            return Color.WHITE;
            case 1:
            return Color.GREEN;
            case 2:
            return Color.RED;
            case 3:
            return Color.YELLOW;
            case 4:
            return Color.BLUE;

        }
        return Color.ORANGE;
    }
}
//my main class
package rubiksCube;

import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Main {

    public static int[][] j = {
            {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
            {1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
            {2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2},
            {3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3},
            {4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4},
            {5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5}
    };
    public static void main(String args[]){
            SimpleGui s = new SimpleGui();
            Display d = new Display();
            int[] x = {0,100,100,0};
            int[] y = {0,0,100,100};
            d.renderSide(0,x,y);
            s.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            s.pack();
            s.setSize(1000,700);
            s.setVisible(true);
            s.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            s.pack();
            s.setSize(1000,1000);
            s.setVisible(true);

    }

}
    //and my gui class
package rubiksCube;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;


public class SimpleGui  extends JFrame{
        int[] px2;
        int[] py2;
        int[] pz2;
        Graphics g2 = null;
        int sN;


    public SimpleGui(){
        JButton solve = new JButton();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        solve.setText("Solve");
        solve.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Control c = new Control();
            c.solve();
        }});
        solve.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){


            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent k) {
                switch (k.getKeyCode()){
                case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_UP:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_0:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_1:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_2:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_3:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_4:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_5:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_6:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_7:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_8:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_9:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_MINUS:

                    break;
                case KeyEvent.VK_EQUALS:

                    break;

                }


            }


            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent k) {


            }


            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent k) {


            }

        });
        JButton random = new JButton();
        random.setText("Randomize");
        random.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            Control c = new Control();
            c.random();
        }});
        p.setVisible(true);
        p.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        solve.setVisible(true);
        random.setVisible(true);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.weightx = 1;
        c.weighty = 1;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        p.add(solve,c);
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.PAGE_START;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        p.add(random,c);
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.gridy = 2;
        JPanel d = new Display();
        d.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        p.add(d,c);
        add(p);
        setContentPane(p);
        setVisible(true);
    }}
```

Can someone please explain that when i say g.fillPolyon(p[y][x]); it doesn't work?
Help please appreciated.
This is on line 23 of my display class.

Answer (score 2):

1. Not calling `super.paintComponent` is going to cause potential issues
2. Not providing a size hint for the `Display` could have it rendered as `0x0`
3. Locations when painting graphics are contextual to the component been painted, that is, the x/y position of `0x0` is the top left corner of the component, specifying X/Y locations that could fall beyond the size of the component won't be painted

The following...

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    SimpleGui s = new SimpleGui();
    Display d = new Display();
    int[] x = {0, 100, 100, 0};
    int[] y = {0, 0, 100, 100};
    d.renderSide(0, x, y);
    s.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    s.setSize(1000, 700);
    s.setVisible(true);
}
```

Is kind of fruitless, as `d` is not actually added to anything the could render it

**Updated**

You need to debug your code further...

I added some `System.out.println` statements to see what you were creating and this is the output...

`---nxn` is the main `for-loops`.  Each series of numbers after it is the `Polygon`

```
---0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
---1x0
0x0
100x0
100x0
0x0
---2x0
0x0
200x0
200x0
0x0
---0x1
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
---1x1
0x0
100x0
100x0
0x0
---2x1
0x0
200x0
200x0
0x0
---0x2
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
---1x2
0x0
100x0
100x0
0x0
---2x2
0x0
200x0
200x0
0x0
---0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
---1x0
0x0
100x0
100x0
0x0
---2x0
0x0
200x0
200x0
0x0
---0x1
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
---1x1
0x0
100x0
100x0
0x0
---2x1
0x0
200x0
200x0
0x0
---0x2
0x0
0x0
0x0
0x0
---1x2
0x0
100x0
100x0
0x0
---2x2
0x0
200x0
200x0
0x0
```

If you look closely, you will see you are drawing straight lines (or empty polygons).

Also the way you've declared and used `p` in `Display` is of concern, as you never reset the `Polygon`s, meaning, on each new repaint, you are simply adding more points to the polys.  Better to pre-caclaulte this and simply paint the result - IMHO

Comment: Sorry i couldn't answer, but thank you for all the suggestions. I now see you are right about the empty polygons. Fixing that now.

Comment: One other question, it seems that rx[1] is always equal to 0 when it is called in any other class besides render side. Why is this?